# Slide animation when guideline percent changes

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation, android-constraintlayout

I have a view that looks like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zKe01.png

When clicked, I want to animate the grey background color so that it slides from the right side to 50% of its initial width:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/s96BX.png

Here is the relevant portion of the layout xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/content_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="44dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="1.0"/>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/background"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/guideline"
        android:background="@drawable/background" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I've tried the following:

```
contentView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        ConstraintSet constraintSet = new ConstraintSet();
        constraintSet.clone(contentView);
        constraintSet.setGuidelinePercent(guideline.getId(), 0.5f);

        TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(contentView);
        constraintSet.applyTo(contentView);
    }
});
```

But instead of the background color sliding from the right to the left (100% to 50%), it sort of just cross-fades.

What am I doing wrong? How would I change my code so the animation SLIDES the background color when the guideline percent changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `android.animation.ValueAnimator` to change the percentage value of your `guideline` inside your `constraintLayout`, the code would be like this:

```
contentView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // initialize your guideline
                // Guideline guideline = findViewById ....
                
                ValueAnimator valueAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(1.0f, 0.5f);
                
                // set duration
                valueAnimator.setDuration(1000);
                // set interpolator and  updateListener to get the animated value
                valueAnimator.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
                
                // update guideline percent value through LayoutParams
                valueAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                        ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams lp = (ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams) guideline.getLayoutParams();
                        // get the float value
                        lp.guidePercent = (Float) animation.getAnimatedValue();
                        // update layout params
                        guideline.setLayoutParams(lp);
                    }

                });
                valueAnimator.start();

            }
        });
```

Comment: That works, but why wasn't it working with `ConstraintSet` in my question?

Comment: As far as I understand, you're not getting a sliding animation, I tried your code, and it shows a sliding animation (exact similar to what the above code did). Can you try passing an `AutoTransition` object parameter to your `beginDelayedTransition` call, Like this: `TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(contentView,AutoTransition())`